# Why is my entitymanager in Playframework 2.5 still null?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, entitymanager, playframework-2.5

I want to use Playframework 2.5 together with Spring and JPA. I found the following template https://github.com/jamesward/play-java-spring where it works perfectly, unfortunately it’s not for Playframework 2.5. So I decided to adapt this template and create my own one for Playframework 2.5. However, my `entitymanager` in my controller `Application` is still `null`. What am I doing wrong? My code looks like the following:

- AppConfig.java

  ```
  package config;
  @Configuration
  @ComponentScan({"daos","services","controllers","models"})
  public class AppConfig {

  }
  ```
- DataConfig.java

  ```
  package config;
  @Configuration
  @EnableTransactionManagement
  public class DataConfig
  {

  @Bean
  public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
      HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
      vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
      vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
      LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
      entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan("models");
      entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
      entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
      entityManagerFactory.setJpaPropertyMap(new HashMap<String, String>(){{

          put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop"); 

          put("hibernate.dialect","org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"); 
      }});
      entityManagerFactory.afterPropertiesSet();

      return entityManagerFactory.getObject();
  }

  @Bean
  public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
      JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory());

      return transactionManager;
  }

  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource() {

      final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

      dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
      dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1");

      return dataSource;
  }
  ```

  }
- Global.java

  ```
  package config;
  @Singleton
  @Configuration
  public class Global 
  {
      private ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

  @Inject
  public Global(ApplicationLifecycle lifecyle)
  {
      this.context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class, DataConfig.class);
      lifecyle.addStopHook(()-> {
          context.close();
          return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
      });
  }
  }
  ```
- Application.java

  ```
  package controllers;
  @Controller
  @Transactional
  @Component
  public class Application extends play.mvc.Controller
  {
  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager em;

  @Transactional
  public Result index()
  {
      System.out.println("******************* EM " + this.em +" *************************");

      return ok(index.render());
  }
  }
  ```

Thank you for your help!